# Difference between discord.py and discord.py[voice]

Tags: discord, discord.py

I plan on making a discord bot using python. What are the differences between discord.py and discord.py[voice]?

Comment: discord.py is a python wrapper meant to be used to communicate with the discord api, discord.py[voice] provides voice functionality as well ( voice chat ).

Comment: Discord.py is the Discord package for discord bot and discord.py[voice] is an extension to handle voice connect

Answer (score 1):

the difference between discord.py and discord[voice] is just PyNaCl library. PyNaCl is used to make discord music bots. If you are currently not looking for making a music bot then you should probably use discord.py when ever you want to add like music bot features.
Then just install PyNaCl library.

In shot:
-> `pip install -U discord.py` for normal discord.py
-> `pip install -U discord.py[voice]` for voice support for your bot

++[For reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#installing)++

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/setup.py

```
extras_require = {
    'voice': ['PyNaCl==1.3.0'],
    'docs': [
        'sphinx==1.8.5',
        'sphinxcontrib_trio==1.1.1',
        'sphinxcontrib-websupport',
    ]
}
```

With `discord.py[voice]` an extra dependency is installed `PyNaCl==1.3.0`.

[PyMaCl](https://pypi.org/project/PyNaCl/) is an optional package but [is needed if you want voice support](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/1ee1b7feea81a70488b1fc2d89a700109c84f8fc/README.rst#optional-packages) for your bot.

Answer (score 0):

Discord.py is the general library while discord.py[voice] is an additional library that allows the discord bot to join VC's and play music, etc...! You can install both by doing:

Discord.py: `pip3 install discord.py`

Discord.py[voice]: `pip3 install discord.py[voice]`

Pip3 means that it would use python3 instead of python! If you need more specifics on how to install it or how it works just use this link -> https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html

Answer (score 0):

By installing only `discord.py`, u just install the basic Module, without voice support, that is, you won't be able to use functions related to Voice Channels and other stuff

But, if you install `discord.py[voice]`, you can also use functions related to Voice Channels and stuff like that...

Install `discord.py` --> `pip install discord.py`

Install `discord.py[voice]` --> `pip install discord.py[voice]`

Answer (score 0):

in discord.py[voice] you can add voice commands

Answer (score 0):

discord.py is the discord framework for making bots WITHOUT voice support so you can't make anything to music if you installed this module: pip install discord.py

discord.py[voice] is the discord framework for making bots WITH voice support so you can make a music bot with this module: pip install discord.py[voice]

Here are some tutorials on how to make a bot and a music bot:

Regular Bot: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYeOw6sTSy6ZGyygcbta7GcpI8a5-Cooc

Music Bot: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYeOw6sTSy6ZIfraPiUsJWuxjqoL47U3u

Answer (score 0):

Discord.py is for basic stuff if you don't intend to make a music bot.
But if you're working on about it, then you must install discord.py[voice].
Otherwise, it won't work

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the Dicord.py[voice] has voice support.

Answer (score 0):

So ...
There is actually only one difference **discord.py** is the **main** part of writing discord bots in python **discord.py[voice]** is an **extension**. With discord.py[voice] you will have a voice_client you can use it, like the following.
`guild.voice_client` or `ctx.voice_client`. The Bot is inable to join one *vc* per server. The Voice Client has different attributes like play and more, if you want to just search for Discord.py Music Bot on YouTube. Another function for stuff like streaming radio is `voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url))`. The `url` should be an website which when opening instantly starts playing something.

Answer (score 0):

`Discord.py[voice]` is the discord.py with voice support, it may be needed when you're working on a music bot. And, `discord.py` is the basic, you know, discord bot development language/ discord framework. Hope it helped, peace <3!